# Issue with getting selected value of select menu in query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

There is a select menu in my page which loads the values from DB. I am able to view the values in select menu. but while displaying the selected value, I am not able to display it properly. i.e. If the value contains any spaces it is not getting full value( EX: if I selected "Wilson Garden", I am getting only "Wilson". It is displaying "Wilson Garden" in select box, when I try to get that value by on change event I got only "Wilson",Same thing happen for all the values which has space in it.

my html is code is:

```
<select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
 <option value="Select Category">Select Category</select>
</select>
```

And my Jquery code is as follows,

```
     $("#select-choice").on('change', function(event) {
              alert( this.value );
              console.log("Category is: " +this.value); // Here I am getting the value.. 
               });
```

// Store the values dynamically in to select menu..

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow","#homePage",function(){

     var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "MYDB"});
     db.transaction(function (tx) {
       tx.executeSql("select distinct Category from Locationlog;", [], function (tx, res) {
            for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
                 $("#select-choice").append('<option value='+res.rows.item(i).Category+'>'+res.rows.item(i).Category+'</option>');
              }
            $("#select-choice").listview('refresh');
          });
         });
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It because you didn't quote the attribute. You need to wrap those values around double quotes.

```
var opt  = '<option value="';
    opt += res.rows.item(i).Category;
    opt += '">';
    opt += res.rows.item(i).Category;
    opt += '</option>';

$("#select-choice").append(opt);
```

Comment: Yes, It is working fine with display value. The list refresh is not happening. The way I am using is the correct way ? if not how can I refresh the list by on change event ?